# Shell script works different in KDE vs Terminal

Tags: shell, sudo, kde, privileges, terminal-emulator

I have a shell script that I created to change the next EFI boot then execute a reboot.  If I execute it in a terminal window it works fine, but if I execute it using an Icon in KDE it reboots, but does not change the next efiboot.  I have tried setting the Icon to run as root, but that didn't make a difference.

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
kdialog --title "Reboot to Windows Prompt" --yesno "Are you sure you want to reboot to Windows?";
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    sudo efibootmgr -n 0
    reboot
else
    kdialog --msgbox "Reboot aborted by user"
fi
```

Someone even suggested having a pause between the efibootmgr and the reboot, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but have you considered launching a terminal + executing your script from an icon.

Right click the icon > Icon Settings > Applicaiton > Command:

`konsole -e /path/to/your/script.sh`

Or if you need the window to stay open for some reason use `-noclose`

Comment: Thanks Chad.  I'm what I consider very green when it comes to Linux.  I'm trying to hide or at least minimize the Konsole itself.  The best i've been able to come up with is --hide-tabbar --hide-menubar --geometry=50x50-1-1.  This puts it in the lower right corner.  I tried making the size 1x1, but then the kdialog doesn't appear.  I also tried to make it way off the screen 50x50+4100+4100, but that didn't work either.  I assume that it looks at you resolution and doesn't let you go beyond that point?  <br>  So in short anyway to make the konsole window itself not visible to the user??

Comment: You can launch konsole in the background using `&`. The icon command would look like this: `konsole -e /path/to/your/script.sh &` You might still see the console flash in the foreground on launch and I'm not sure if you can prevent that.